# Python def function title

Tags: python, function

I want to make a function but in the title it won't let me add a fullstop,

For Example:

```
 def system.do():
```

But it won't let have the full stop so how can I get it so it does?

Thanks For The Help!

Comment: Why do you want a full stop? Perhaps you want a class instead?

Comment: And why not def system_do()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't define a normal function like that, as `.` is not allowed in an identifier.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers):

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
```

The only way you can create such function is by defining a static method named `do` in a class named `system`.

```
class system:
    @staticmethod
    def do():
        pass
print system.do()
```

Comment: This is not the only way, it doesn't have to be a staticmethod. Further, you could also write a "system" module or create any kind of (mutable) object named "system" and attach a function to it under the name "do". Your approach is a good approach though, apart from avoiding the goal altogether.